# Apache wont start after copy zend library xampp

Tags: apache, zend-framework

after copying zend library in my zend proj and refresh the page Apache wont start.

it show me this error : Appache Http Server has stopped working

i use of xampp , version 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague. There can be a number of things that went wrong and you didn't give us enough background information on the install. (like config files you changed, directories you renamed, etc.)

If you cannot start Apache, the first place to check is the Apache error log file for problems. It will most likely have an error that we can help you troubleshoot.

I am not familiar with xampp directory paths but will take a guess that you need to look here: `/xampp/apache/logs/error.log`.

Answer (score 0):

i`ve change my xampp version to 1.7.3 , now it work nice